# directory permissions adding user in a group

Tags: permissions, debian, chown

I added a user using `useradd`

`useradd -g upperdevs myuser`

But when I do an `id` check I didn't see the upperdevs group.

```
id myuser
#uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),27(sudo)
```

Probably this was the issue why I can't write to certain_dir, by doing `ls -l`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root upperdevs 4096 Sep  8 13:35 certain_dir
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Was the user already there? Anyway, just run

```
adduser myuser upperdevs
```

Comment: The user already exists.